# Spricht man in Südtirol (für Deutsche) verständlichen Dialekt?

Tags: dialect, regional, south-tyrol

Südtirol ist ja ein recht beliebtes Urlaubsziel für Wanderer und Wintersportler aus Deutschland. Persönlich war ich noch nicht dort. Darum die Frage, wie weit kommt man mit Hochdeutsch in Südtirol eigentlich? Bei uns gibts ja schon Verständnisschwierigkeiten innerhalb von Regionen (lustiges Beispiel ist immer wieder Einblendung von hochdeutschen Untertiteln beim Interview von Niederbayern im Bayerischen Fernsehen!).

Sind die Tageszeitungen in perfekten Hochdeutsch in Südtirol oder ist das mehr ein Brei von subregionalen Dialekten je nach Bezirk. Sollte man etwas firm im bairischen Dialekt sein? Gibts vielleicht eine gute Kulturradiostation bei der man etwas schnuppern kann oder eine Kulturseite im Netz die sich mit der Sprache und/oder aktuellen Ereignissen dort befasst im vorherrschenden Dialekt? Fernsehen prägt ja Sprache ungemein, was schaut der typische Südtiroler für Fernsehsender, deutsche/italienische/österreichische?

Comment: ...mit besten Grüßen an @splattne ;-)

Comment: @Jan danke! Werde gleich mal antworten.

Comment: Mit Hochdeutsch (Standarddeutsch) kommt man im ganzen deutschen Sprachraum, sogar in der Schweiz, gut zurecht. Man darf nur nicht immer erwarten, dass man mitgelauschte Gespräche unter Eingeborenen versteht.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

So klingt der Südtiroler Dialekt ungefähr:

> Wenn i die Frog in meinem Dialekt beontworten tat, donn tat des epper so klingen. I vermut, es meischte waret verständlich, vor ollem die "modernen" Wörter. Es gipp a poor Lautverschiebungen, de man kennen sollet, zum Beispiel werd es "a" oft als "o" ("å") ausgesprochen.

In Südtirol leben rund 500.000 Menschen. Davon sind ca. 70% deutscher und 25% italienischer Muttersprache. Die restlichen 5% sprechen [Ladinisch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladinische_Sprache), eine alte rätoromanische Sprache.

Die deutschsprachigen Südtiroler sprechen im Alltag miteinander vorwiegend im Dialekt. In den Schulen wird normalerweise in Hochdeutsch unterrichtet und kommuniziert; viele Südtiroler klingen allerdings etwas holprig, wenn sie Hochdeutsch sprechen, da sie u. a. Fallfehler machen. Das liegt daran, dass im Dialekt häufig der Akkusativ gewählt wird, wo in der Hochsprache der Dativ verwendet wird:

> Des Hemp honn i in Bozen unter die [Lauben](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bozner_Lauben) gekaft.
>   (Dieses Hemd habe ich in Bozen unter den Lauben gekauft.)

Ich vermute, das eine bundesdeutsche Person, die nördlich des [Weißwurstäquators](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wei%C3%9Fwurst%C3%A4quator) lebt, das meiste verstehen wird, was Südtiroler dialektal von sich geben. Es gibt jedoch sicher eine Reihe von häufig benutzten Ausdrücken, die nur den Einheimischen oder evtl. Bewohnern von Nachbarregeionen (Nord-/Osttirol in Österreich, evtl. Bayern, Salzburg und Kärnten) geläufig sind. Einige Beispiele:

- gleim (nahe)
- Glump (unnützes Zeug, Dinge mit schlechter Qualität)
- Schlatterer (Taugenichts)
- tratzen (necken)
- Poppele (Baby)

Da Südtirol nach dem Ende des ersten Weltkriegs von Italien annektiert wurde, finden sich im Südtiroler Dialekt mittlerweile auch viele Italianismen, wie zum Beispiel

- Hydrauliker (Installateur)
- ma dai..., dai?, ma va?, seggo? (wirklich?)
- Targa (Autokennzeichen)

In Südtirol gibt es zahlreiche private Radiostationen und eine öffentliche, den Sender "RAI Südtirol". Die RAI strahlt vorwiegend in den Abendstunden auch ein Fernsehprogramm aus, deren bekannteste Sendung die "Tagesschau" ist. Der österreichische Rundfunk produziert täglich "[Südtirol heute](http://tvthek.orf.at/programs/1277675-Suedtirol-heute)", eine 20 Minuten lange Boulevard-Nachrichtensendung, die auch in einem Internetarchiv verfügbar ist.

Es gibt weiters zwei Tageszeitungen: die "Dolomiten" und die "Tageszeitung". Beide sind - meiner Meinung nach - keine journalistischen Glanzleistungen. Die "ff" ist das einzige regionale wöchentliche Nachrichtenmagazin und behandelt vorwiegend Südtiroler Themen.

Wer mehr erfahren möchte: Es gibt in Wikipedia ein Kapitel zu den Tiroler Dialekten: [Südtirolerisch](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialekte_in_Tirol#S.C3.BCdtirol). Außerdem zum Nachschlagen: [Das Südtiroler Dialekt-Wörterbuch](http://oschpele.ritten.org/).

Comment: Danke. Schön, dass wir einen Insider hier haben. "keine journal. Glanzleistungen" Gemessen an der deutschen Presse die du liest? Oder habt ihr da auch schon eine Berlusconisierung der Medienlandschaft? Seid ihr bei der Wahl des ital. Parlaments stimmberechtigt oder nur für das südtirol. Landesparlament?

Comment: @Hauser wie eben regionale Blätter so sind... die eine Tageszeitung hat quasi das Monopol und berichtet eher konservativ und tendenziös, die andere ist reißerisch und arbeitet unter der Gürtellinie. Als italienische Staatsbürger wählen wir auch bei den ital. Parlamentswahlen; Südtirol hat als autonome Provinz allerdings viele Kompetenzen vom Staat übernommen und genießt somit eine Sonderstellung (wie einige andere ital. Provinzen).

Comment: Ihr habt noch die Superworte "zuscht, ebbes, lei, inni, obi, aui, garling und firi" vergessen. Das ist so der südtiroler Alltagswortschatz (eine in Südtirol lebende deutsche Deutschlehrerin mit Kulturschock;-))

Comment: Das "weiters" im Text gibt der Duden übrigens als österreichisch an.

Comment: @CarsteS: Das ist kein Wunder. Früher war ganz Tirol im Besitz der Habsburger (ab 1363; mit kurzen Unterbrechungen) und ab 1804 ein Kronland des Kaisertums Österreich. Erst vor weniger als 100 Jahren (1919) fiel mit dem Ende des 1. Weltkrieges ein Teil von Tirol an Italien. Seit 1946 (bis heute) übt Österreich (genauer: die österr. Bundesregierung) eine Schutzfunktion über Südtirol aus. Daher wird auch in Südtirols Schulen Österreichisches Deutsch unterrichtet. In Südtirol war - wie in Österreich - auch niemals der Duden das offizielle Wörterbuch, sondern das ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch).

Answer (score 4):

Einen sauber transkribierten Südtiroler Dialog kann der deutsche Tourist vermutlich lesen und nach Erläuterung einiger Wörter auch verstehen. Bei der gesprochenen Sprache ist das etwas anders. Nach meiner Erfahrung sprechen Südtiroler mit deutschsprachigen Nicht-Südtirolern, auch mit Österreichern, eine sehr geglättete Version ihres Dialekts, untereinander aber so, dass auch Österreicher ihnen oft nicht folgen können. Ob unter die Österreicher hier auch Nordtiroler fallen, weiß ich nicht. Es sind nicht nur die Begriffe, sondern vor allem die Lautung und der Sprachrhythmus, in die man sich erst einmal einhören muss. Deutsche Besucher müssen jedoch keine Angst haben, sich nicht verständigen zu können oder Südtiroler nicht zu verstehen, die sich ihnen verständlich machen wollen.

Answer (score 2):

Ich komme aus Südtirol und muss sagen, dass der Dialekt sich schon von Dorf zu Dorf unterscheidet. Ich sage jedes Wort, das einer von den anderen Kommentaren da oben geschrieben hat, schon anders. Hochdeutsch kann eigentlich jeder:)

Answer (score 1):

1. Es gibt schon Dialektwörter, die man sich schwer herleiten kann, [»in galing« etwa für »bald einmal«](http://oschpele.ritten.org/index.php?wort=galing&submit=%3E&site=3), »Ehrtig« für »Dienstag«, »feartn« für »voriges Jahr« u.v.a. Viele sind aber auch nur allgemein im Süden gebräuchliche (z. T. [alemannische](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alemannische_Dialekte)) Ausdrücke wie das praktische »heuer« oder »innert« als Zeitangaben, die die »preußisch« orientierte deutsche Linguistik gern links liegen lässt, polemisch gesagt. Manches ist historisch: »Luxusauto« für Pkw zur Unterscheidung von – jedenfalls in der Nachkriegszeit – sinnvolleren Vehikeln.
2. Natürlich hat die »Dolomiten« ein Lokalmonopol, und – wie alle Zeitungen – Tendenz. Gemacht ist das Blatt aber bewundernswert gut: Bilder zu jedem Artikel, und dennoch nicht Boulevard, geographisch geordnete Nachrichten, signierte Meinungen, Lesermeinungen (-briefe) getrennt von Politikermeinungen, ordentlich faktische Nachrichten und nicht nur proporzorientierte Politikersprüche, die in Deutschland gerne als »Nachrichten« verkauft werden.
   Fritz Jörn

Comment: Willkommen, aber das ist leider keine Antwort auf die Frage, sondern wahrscheinlich ein längerer Kommentar zu einer der Antworten.

Comment: Danke, ja. Also konkret zu den Fragen ganz oben:

Comment: Danke, ja. Also konkret zu den Fragen ganz oben:
1. »Wie weit kommt man mit Hochdeutsch in Südtirol eigentlich?« – Überall hin! Ist auch nicht anders als in Ruhpolding. Italiener können aber oft nicht gut Deutsch. Die sind aber in der Minderheit.
2. »Sind die Tageszeitungen in perfektem Hochdeutsch?« Ja. Radiostationen, TV auch. Wie in Nordtirol oder in Bayern auch. Gehn’S doch einmal auf stol.it – da sehen Sie keinen Unterschied zum Standarddeutsch.

Answer (score 1):

Da hier manche Antworten sowieso aus persönlicher Erfahrung stammen, füge ich einmal meine hinzu:

Mein Stiefvater kommt aus Friesland, ich aus Bayern.

Wir hatten  über die Jahre einige Mal die Erfahrung gemacht, wie weit wir die Dialekte aus jeweiligen Nachbarstaaten verstehen:

- Er versteht Niederländisch, obwohl er es nicht spricht. Er kann aber *platt* sprechen und generell verstehen ihn dann auch Holländer, die kein deutsch sprechen
- Ich spreche (noch) bayerischen Dialekt und mich verstehen Tiroler, Südtiroler, selbst die, die wirklich nur südtiroler Dialekt (neber der italienischen Amtssprache) verstehen. Umgekehrt verstehe ich deren Dialekte.
- Ich verstehe kein Niederländisch und habe mit echtem *Plattdeutsch* meine Not. Umgekehrt versteht mein Stiefvater nur Bahnhof, wenn's wirklich bajuwarisch zur Sache geht.
- In beiden Fällen gibt's Extremfälle, wo es ... sagen wir mal "ländlich" wird. Will meinen, wenn die Sprecher jeweils aus etwas abgelegenen Dörfern in Watt und Alp stammen, dann hilft nur noch Zeichensprache. ;)

Comment: Vielleicht sollte mal jemand anmerken, dass Friesisch und Platt nicht deutsch sind, zumindest nicht im Sinne von unserer Sprache, dem Neuhochdeutschen.

Comment: @deponensvogel Na das werde ich meinem Stiefvater mit Genuss entgegen werfern, wenn er wieder mit der ollen "Caesar/Tacitus' hässlisches Bergvolk am Rande der Alpen" Kamelle daherkommt. ;)